# Understanding ASP.NET ConnectionPool and string security

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, connection-pooling

I'm writing an application in ASP.NET, where I do frequent SQL Connections and by frequent I mean every 2 seconds. It's real time data application.
BD Engine is SQL SERVER 2008R2.

Each user connects to at least two different databases.
My problem is I still cant understand the connection pooling and how much of them connections I'll have after some queries.

I implemented the following methods:

```
private static string composeConnectionString(string connectTo)
{
    StringBuilder sqlSB = new StringBuilder("Data Source=");
        sqlSB.Append(dataSource);
        sqlSB.Append(";Min Pool Size=");
        sqlSB.Append(minPoolSize);
        sqlSB.Append(";Max Pool Size=");
        sqlSB.Append(maxPoolSize);
        sqlSB.Append(";Connection Timeout=");
        sqlSB.Append(connectionTimeout);
        sqlSB.Append(";Initial Catalog=");
        sqlSB.Append(connectTo);
        sqlSB.Append(";Integrated Security=");
        sqlSB.Append(integratesSecurity);
        sqlSB.Append(";User Id=");
        sqlSB.Append(userId);
        sqlSB.Append(";Password=");
        sqlSB.Append(password);
        sqlSB.Append(";MultipleActiveResultSets=");
        sqlSB.Append(multipleActiveResultSets);
    return sqlSB.ToString();
}

public static SqlConnection getConnection(string connectTo)
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    string connectionString = composeConnectionString(connectTo);

    try
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (connection != null)
            connection = null;
        ExceptionLogger.LogException(ex, connectionString);
    }
    return connection;
}
```

At this point, I begin to question if new ConnectionPool is creater for every SQLConnection I seek?
How secure is the connection string?

Ask me for updates if something seem blurry.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why do you build dynamically the connection string? Are those parameters ever changed during the lifetime of your application?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but if you mean the SQL Server connection pool, then no, a new pool is not created for each connection, but each connection will pull from the connection pool  (simplified). As for "secure", then it depends on what you do with it. If you mean you can get information in one connection about another connection then no. However if you expose a connection string to other parts of your application it's up to you to make that secure.

Comment: @Steve I build it dynamically, because I connect to different DBs depending the user. I don't know to which DBs I'll connect until I read their configuration file.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Referring the pool, it's a relief. I guess different pool is for different BDs or still is the same?
Regarding security, I mean where this string travels? Is more secure building it dynamically than putting it in Web.Config right?

Comment: There are a number of different conditions for when it creates different pool, based on the differences in the connection string. So yes, different DBs get different pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depends of your configuration. If you configure your pool for at least one connection and a maximum of 3, when your first connection happens, if pooling is enabled, the connection will check for at least 1 and maximum of 3.

> The pooler maintains ownership of the physical connection. It manages
>   connections by keeping alive a set of active connections for each
>   given connection configuration. Whenever a user calls Open on a
>   connection, the pooler looks for an available connection in the pool.
>   If a pooled connection is available, it returns it to the caller
>   instead of opening a new connection. When the application calls Close
>   on the connection, the pooler returns it to the pooled set of active
>   connections instead of closing it. Once the connection is returned to
>   the pool, it is ready to be reused on the next Open call.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

2. About the connection string, if you use user name and password as  credentials, you have a security issue. You can use Windows Authentication to ensure your connection string does not have any sensitive data, or, if you're using IIS, you can store the connection string on it to protect your data.

Read more about connection string here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

And about protecting the connection string here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pretty insightful, thank you.
Regarding the pooling, I was worried that it gets different pool every time I build the string.
Regarding security, setting Persist Security Info=False and using ConnectionStringBuilder should be enough for read-only credentials.